# angular 2 using services to route

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services

I want to create a service which does my routing. I figured that I'll be needing the Router Service and ROUTER_DIRECTIVES. The Router Service I can simple inject with a constructor inside my service.

How do I add the ROUTER_DIRECTIVES?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ROUTER_DIRECTIVES must be set on components where you use corresponding directives like router-outlet or routerLink.

```
@Component({
  (...)
  template: '
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  ',
  directives: [ ROUTER_DIRECTIVES ]
})
(...)
```

They don't apply to services. Only router providers do because you want to inject related providers using dependency injection.